# How to display vertex colors in Viewport Shading Mode

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, color

So I'm pretty new to blender and I'm trying to make some visualisations for a paper I'm hoping to publish. So far I've got my tractography and cortical matter loaded into Blender and I've managed to give some colour information on the tractography. However, I want to change the colours to the standardised tractography colours which appear by selecting paint vertex and being in the solid view. Does anyone know how I would achieve this? I've attached the vertex view that I want and the current nodes I've implemented and the colours they produce.

Thank you in advance for any help!

[image: Vertex paint colours: The goal]

[image: Current node implementation]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I have egg on my face. Very simple solution, after deviating away from tutorials and just playing around. Here is the solution. Thanks for the upvote and hopefully this helps someone else:
[image: SOLUTION]

Comment: It should be noted that if you leave the layer name field empty, the node will automatically pick the first vertex color layer of the mesh. (Not a problem if you only have one, but it can be confusing)